# Reflecting constant properties/fields in .net

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, constants

I have a class which looks like as follows:

```
public class MyConstants
{
    public const int ONE = 1;
    public const int TWO = 2;

    Type thisObject;
    public MyConstants()
    {
        thisObject = this.GetType();
    }

    public void EnumerateConstants()
    {
        PropertyInfo[] thisObjectProperties = thisObject.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in thisObjectProperties)
        {
            //need code to find out of the property is a constant
        }
    }
}
```

Bascially it is trying to reflect itself. I know how to reflect fields ONE, & TWO. But how do I know if it is a constant or not?

Comment: I take that back...I cannot find the fields ONE & TWO.

Comment: They aren't just fields, they're static fields, not instance fields.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's because they're fields, not properties.  Try:

```
    public void EnumerateConstants() {        
        FieldInfo[] thisObjectProperties = thisObject.GetFields();
        foreach (FieldInfo info in thisObjectProperties) {
            if (info.IsLiteral) {
                //Constant
            }
        }    
    }
```

Edit: DataDink's right, it's smoother to use IsLiteral

Comment: uh yeah realized it too late... Yeah is anything const essentially static too?

Comment: DataDink's answer is actually a little smoother.  And yes; try adding && info.IsStatic.

Comment: wht is the difference between IsLiteral & IsStatic if both are true?

Comment: Um . . . something can be static but not constant.

Comment: To elaborate, something that's constant and set at program initialization can never change for any independent object instance, so it might as well be static, given that no two instances will ever have different values of it.  However, something that's static does not necessarily need to be constant (literal), as its value may change throughout the life of the program.  Make sense?

Answer (score 5):

FieldInfo objects actually have a ton of "IsSomething" booleans right on them:

```
var m = new object();
foreach (var f in m.GetType().GetFields())
if (f.IsLiteral)
{
    // stuff
}
```

Which saves you a tiny ammount of code over checking the attributes anyways.